# HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was '' + windowsazure

Tags: authentication, azure, windows-authentication, azure-virtual-network

The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was '' + i am working on windows azure service bus plugin,i got service endpoint and  i got verified with the authentication through the plugin registration tool.when i run the code i was facing with the above issue as The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was '', can any one please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I just came into this issue.

I created a queue in Azure Service Bus and register it as an endpoint in Registration Plugin tool (Authentication was verified successfully).

But when I tested it in CRM, message was not sent to the endpoint due to this error.

Went through some articles on Internet and I resolved this issue by changing following things in the Service Endpoint Registration dialog:

**Contract** : Queue

**Claim** : UserId

Hope this helps.